# Display images stored outside the public folder in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, profile, photo

I have my photo folder stored in the data folder in a Zend Framework application. when i try to read the image files from the data folder to display as a user profile photo in my view i cant get it display and it only show up when i disable my view and layout.

This is my sample code:

```
$appShortPath = $photPlugin->getPathToFileFolders();

$databaseFile = '2011/08/18/17c7025cd9f3436e4ad1c02635cc6754.jpg';           

$appPath = $appShortPath . '/data/UploadPhotos/';

if(!isset($databaseFile))
{
  return false;
}

$fullPath = $appPath . $databaseFile;

if(!file_exists($fullPath))
{
  return false;
}

$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
$this->view->layout()->disableLayout();

$image = readfile($fullPath);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$this->getResponse()
  ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');   

$this->view->logo = $image;
```

I want to get the profile photos and display it in the user profile page

hope someone can help - thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use this, but has problem with some older versions of IE

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Answer (score -2):

Why are you trying to set a header as type image/jpeg?

Can you not just set `$this->view->logo = /path/to/jpeg`

Then in your view script

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->logo; ?>" alt="" />
```

Comment: He said a non-public directory, so he is trying to read it and then output the data.